# Remove last comma from a cell in a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete the last comma from each cell of a dynamic range.

The macro doesn't delete the comma, it just selects the range.

```
Sub selecting()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set StartCell = Range("D1")

'Find Last Row and Column
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).row
LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Select Range
sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select

With ActiveCell
    If Right(.Value, 1) = "," Then .Value = Right(.Value, Len(.Value) - 1)

End With

End Sub
```

Here is what is returned

[image]

Comment: `.Value = Left(.Value, Len(.Value) - 1)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to loop through the cells in the selected range...?

Comment: "Be careful to distinguish between the active cell and the selection. The active cell is a single cell inside the current selection. The selection may contain more than one cell, but only one is the active cell." - [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.window.activecell)

Comment: Try to [avoid using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: You can do this simply in Power Query with `Trim.End`, but maybe a better approach would be to change the method you used to construct the strings in the first place. It might be simpler to change that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to remove the last character from each cell in column D, try this variation on braX's comment. It loops trough each used cell in column 4 and deletes the last character.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cel In .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp))
        cel.Value = Left(cel, Len(cel) - 1)
    Next cel
End With
```

Comment: I think looping is the correct way of doing this, however OP wants a check for a comma. Otherwise you are removing the last character unwanted. Also, you are using an implicit sheet reference on `Cells(Rows.Count...)`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. Your code worked, and did exactly what I needed!

Comment: @AleksLi I think the problem was the code or formula you used to combine the cells added the last `,` which could probably be fixed without using this additional code.

Answer (score 1):

The most conventional way would be to loop over your cells:

---

```
Sub Replacing()

Dim lr As Long, lc As Long
Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Find Last Row and Column
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Go through range
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, lc), .Cells(lr, lc))
    For Each cl In rng
        If Right(cl.Value, 1) = "," Then cl.Value = Left(cl.Value, Len(cl.Value) - 1)
    Next cl

End With

End Sub
```

---

Better would be to go through memory if your range is actually much larger (for performance sake)

```
Sub Replacing()

Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, x As Long
Dim arr As Variant

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Find Last Row and Column
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Go through array
    arr = .Range(.Cells(1, lc), .Cells(lr, lc)).Value
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If Right(arr(x, 1), 1) = "," Then arr(x, 1) = Left(arr(x, 1), Len(arr(x, 1)) - 1)
    Next x

    'Write array back to range
    .Range(.Cells(1, lc), .Cells(lr, lc)).Value = arr

End With

End Sub
```

---

And a more less conventional way (alright for small ranges I guess) would be to evalate a range and avoid an iteration. This however comes at the cost of an array formula:

```
Sub Replacing()

Dim lr As Long, lc As Long
Dim rng As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Find Last Row and Column
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Evaluate your range
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, lc), .Cells(lr, lc))
    rng.Value = .Evaluate("IF(RIGHT(" & rng.Address & ",1)="","",LEFT(" & rng.Address & ",LEN(" & rng.Address & ")-1)," & rng.Address & ")")

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `Replace()` function:

```vba
For Each Cell in Range.Cells
    Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Text, ",", "")
Next Cell
```

Edit: After testing, replaced `.Text` with `.Value`

Edit 2: I'd also like to add, why are you selecting the range? My supposition is that you are selecting it to enable use of `ActiveCell` but you can simply manipulate the range without selecting it. Selecting the range is asking to incur errors. My suggestion is:

```vba
Dim rplcRng as Range
Set rplcRange = sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

For Each Cell in rplcRng.Cells
    Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Text, ",", "")
Next Cell
```

Edit 3: added "s"s

Comment: Down voting because your code replaces all commas in the cells, not the last comma, as the OP ask. The correct approach is the one in the comment by @braX.